# Acces to object scope in a function with multiple params in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got this function:

```js
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
  let inDebounce;

  return function() {
    const context = this
    const args = arguments
    clearTimeout(inDebounce)
    inDebounce = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay)
  }
}

var likes_btn = document.getElementsByClassName("js-submit-like");

for (var i = 0; i < likes_btn.length; i++) {
  likes_btn[i].addEventListener('click', debounce(function(el) {
    alert("hello");

    el.preventDefault();
  }, 500));
}
```

So the thing is, that I need to use the `.preventDefault()` before the debounce gets executed. Currently, what really happens is that is executed at the end of `debounce()`, not into the function scope.

How can I acces into the function scope? Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean "... before *the function passed to `debounce` is executed" or "... when the function returned by `debounce ` is executed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate `debouncer` callback that the listener can close over:

```js
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
  let inDebounce;

  return function() {
    const context = this
    const args = arguments
    clearTimeout(inDebounce)
    inDebounce = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay)
  }
}

var likes_btn = document.getElementsByClassName("js-submit-like");

for (let i = 0; i < likes_btn.length; i++) {
  const button = likes_btn[i];
  const debouncer = debounce((e) => console.log("Hello", button), 500); // you can also use e.target to refer to the button
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
    debouncer(e);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<a class="js-submit-like" href="http://www.facebook.com/">Like</a>

<a class="js-submit-like" href="http://www.facebook.com/">Like 2</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just move it outside of the debouncer callback:

```
const debouncer = debounce(() => alert("hello"), 500);
likes_btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   debouncer(event);
});
```

That might be a bit more elegant with some chained functions:

```
 const both = (fn1, fn2) => (...args) => (fn1(...args), fn2(...args));
 const stop = event => event.preventDefault();
 const listen = (el, name, handler) => el.addEventListener(name, handler);

 for(const btn of likes_btn) {
   listen(btn, "click", both(
    debounce(() => alert("hello"), 500),
    stop
   ));
}
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `debounce` then? Every time the handler is executed, a new debounced function will be created (i.e. the event handler is *not* debounced, all you are doing is delaying each executing).

Comment: Don't use an arrow function, you won't be able to change its context with `.apply()`.

Comment: @FelixKling The purpose of `debounce()` is to reduce the frequency that the callback function is executed when the events happen rapidly. The default action should always be prevented.

Comment: @Barmar: I understand that. But that only works if *the same function returned by `debounce`* is called repeatedly. That's not the case in the first solution. *edit:* *was the case.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I see what you're saying -- there's a different `inDebounce` timer each time the event occurs, rather that one for the element whole series of events.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, that :) But Jonas fixed it. I also could have made my comment clearer...

Comment: @JonasW I tested your code and the `stop` function is never called. `fn1(...args)` returns undefined so `fn2(...args)` is never called.

Comment: @guillaume oh, thanks. I'm definetly too tired to answer now... :/